# In SSMS is there a way to export a list of job steps in a SQL Server Agent job?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

**In SSMS is there a way to export a list of job steps in a SQL Server Agent job?**

The reason I'm asking is that I've been asked to organize a long list of job steps placed in three different jobs. This is something I'd like to share with my team in an Excel document so that we can make notes, demonstrate grouping and sorting ideas, argue about it, etc.

Is there a way I can export this list, or at least print it? I could do a screenshot, except that the list extends past the screen?  I'm *not* looking forward to keying this by hand into Excel.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Right click it -> Script Job To ... ?

Comment: Thanks.  This helps, but in a different way.  By selecting "Script Job As" -> "Create To" -> "Clipboard", I am able to paste a script the steps in the job.  This certainly helps with a documentation requirement. Very helpful.  But what I was hoping to do was be able to export the list of step names and types, maybe as a table. That is what I still need to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the server;

```
select 
    job.name,
    steps.step_id,
    steps.step_name,
    steps.command
from MSDB.dbo.SysJobs job
    inner join MSDB.dbo.SysJobSteps steps on steps.Job_Id = job.Job_Id
where job.enabled = 1
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: This is perfect. The only addition I would add for my use is the "Use [database name]; go" block at the very beginning.